# Can't access php files on local apache server

Tags: php, apache, apache2, hhvm

I have setup a local apache2 server, and it works and display correctly for any html files located at `home/user/website`, but it gives me an `404 error` when i try to access php files.

i.e:

```
~/website ls
hello.php  index.html  test2.html  test.php
```

`127.0.1.1/index.html` and `127.0.1.1/test2.html` loads normally but `127.0.1.1/hello.php` and `127.0.1.1/test.php` gives me a 404

Theres no trace of error on the error.log file though there's a 404 GET on the `access.log` file:

`127.0.0.1 - - [25/Sep/2014:00:35:01 -0300] "GET /hello.php HTTP/1.1" 404 273 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36"`

I have this on the `apache2.conf`, not sure if it's correct:

```
<Directory /home/user/website>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I configured apache2 to run with hhvm trough the scripts that comes with hhvm.
My system is ubuntu 14.04
Thanks.

Comment: file permissions set ok?

Comment: Like r/w permissions? Both .html and .php have the same permissions which are -rw-rw-r--, do php files need some extra permissions?

Comment: Can you post your full apache2 configuration file ? You're saying you use HHVM but you don't show the relevant part of your `httpd.conf`. BTW, which version of Apache 2 are you running ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this answer on: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/3472

I had to set `hhvm.server.fix_path_info = true` in `/etc/hhvm/server.ini`, now it works.